# shortcode change variable base on user

Tags: shortcode

How would I put this together.

For plugin Contact Form 7 Data Base how would I add in the "Submitted Login" (user display name) to the search="name"

Original Shortcode

```
[cfdb-table form="Contact form 1" show="Submitted Login,your-email,your-message" search="AndrewA"]
```

Tried to put this together a few ways, none worked.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="Contact form 1" show="Submitted Login,your-email,your-message" search="' . $current_user->display_name .'"]');?>
```

This is so users can see their contact form data they have submitted.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the original shortcode working with `do_shortcode()` ?

Comment: Yes it works with 'do_shortcode()'. I hope it can work both ways. In the theme and in the post editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this works for you in the template:

```
$s='[cfdb-table form="Contact form 1" show="Submitted Login,your-email,your-message" search="AndrewA"]';
echo do_shortcode($s);
```

then you could try:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$s = sprintf('[cfdb-table form="Contact form 1" show="Submitted Login,your-email,your-message" search="%s"]',$current_user->display_name); 
echo do_shortcode($s);
```

Comment: That worked great!